# Why am I receiving the error: object '.' not found

Tags: r, tidymodels

I’m testing the tidymodels package to do some modeling.

So far I started with the basic workflow (recipe + spec), no cross-validation.

Here you have a repex for a sample dataframe, with one endpoint column (factor of 0 and 1), and 20 descriptor variables (genes, numeric variables).
For this I want to perform an SVM with a radial kernel for all the genes predicting the endpoint. The formula would be  `endpoint ~ ., data = data`

However, I’m getting the following error:

```
> svm_fit <- fit(svm_wflow, data)
Error in eval_tidy(env$formula[[2]], env$data) : object '.' not found
```

Apparently is not recognizing the `.`  in the formula, but not sure why, nor how to fix it.

```
library(tidymodels)
tidymodels_prefer()


# Create the endpoint variable
endpoint <- factor(rep(c(1, 0), each = 10))

# Create the gene columns
genes <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20 * 20), ncol = 20))

# Combine the endpoint and gene columns into a dataframe
data <- data.frame(endpoint, genes)

# Recipe
svm_linear_rec <- 
  recipe(endpoint ~ ., data = data) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors()) %>% 
  step_dummy(endpoint)

# Spec
svm_spec <- 
  svm_rbf(cost = tune(), rbf_sigma = tune()) %>% 
  set_engine("kernlab") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")


# Workflow
svm_wflow <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_model(svm_spec) %>% 
  add_recipe(svm_linear_rec)

# Fit model
svm_fit <- fit(svm_wflow, data)
```

Comment: familiarise yourself with https://parsnip.tidymodels.org/reference/fit.html, you are not specifying the arguments fot `fit()` correctly I think

Answer (score 3):

You are getting that specific error because you are using `step_dummy()` on the outcome `endpoint`, so when it is time to fit the model, it tries to use `endpoint` as the outcome, but that variable doesn't exists anymore as it was removed by `step_dummy()`.

When using {tidymodels} for classification you shouldn't need to create dummy variables for the outcome.

With the specification of your model, if you want to `tune()` the parameters you need to use one of the `tune_*()` functions. See more information here https://www.tidymodels.org/start/tuning/

Cross-posted here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/why-am-i-receiving-the-error-object-not-found/175571